# Hibernate OneToMany Relationship on save does an insert and then a update, how to avoid the redundant update?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, one-to-many, bidirectional

I am trying to resolve redundant Update statements that are getting executed while saving a OneToMany relationship. I know this question has been asked before, but I didnt get it to work. I've tried all the suggestions but no luck. Please take a look at my Entity classes in OneToMany bi directional relationship below-

Parent OneToMany side of relationship:

```
@Entity(name = 'ReconciliationModel')
@Table(name = 'reconciliation')
class ReconciliationModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 'reconciliation_sequence')
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = 'reconciliation_reference_id', allocationSize = 1, name = 'reconciliation_sequence')
    @Column(name = 'reconciliation_id')
    Long id

    @Column(name = 'process_date')
    LocalDate processDate

    @Column(name = 'reconciliation_date')
    LocalDate reconciliationDate

    @Column(name = 'reconciliation_flag')
    boolean reconciliationFlag

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = 'reconciliationModel', cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<ReconciliationDetailModel> reconciliationDetailModels = []

    void addReconciliationRecoveryDetail(ReconciliationRecoveryModel reconciliationRecoveryModel) {
        reconciliationRecoveryModels.add(reconciliationRecoveryModel)
        reconciliationRecoveryModel.reconciliationModel = this
    }

    void removeReconciliationRecoveryDetail(ReconciliationRecoveryModel reconciliationRecoveryModel) {
        reconciliationRecoveryModels.remove(reconciliationRecoveryModel)
        reconciliationRecoveryModel.reconciliationModel = null
    }
//For brevity, removed groovy setters, constructors and other annotations that were used
}
```

Child(Many to One side of relationship)

```
@Entity(name = 'ReconciliationRecoveryModel')
@Table(name = 'reconciliation_recovery_detail_test')
class ReconciliationRecoveryModel {

    @EmbeddedId
    ReconciliationRecoveryIdentity id

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = 'reconciliation_id', nullable = false, updatable = false)
    ReconciliationModel reconciliationModel

}
```

While setting the ReconciliationModel, I am creating a ReconciliationRecoveryModel(child) and adding it to parent using addReconciliationRecoveryDetail method in the parent. 
Then using entityManager.save(parent) to persist the complete relationship.

However, when I look at the SQLs that are generated, I see that a insert of child and again update of child happens and all the updates are redundant here. Below is the log I am seeing.

```
[DEBUG] 2019-11-15 11:58:06,520 http-nio-8080-exec-2 org.hibernate.SQL - {} -insert into reconciliation_recovery_detail_test (reconciliation_id, recovery_date, recovery_type, reference_document_number) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
[TRACE] 2019-11-15 11:58:06,521 http-nio-8080-exec-2 org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - {} - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [152812]
[TRACE] 2019-11-15 11:58:06,521 http-nio-8080-exec-2 org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - {} - binding parameter [2] as [DATE] - [2019-11-10]
[TRACE] 2019-11-15 11:58:06,521 http-nio-8080-exec-2 org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - {} - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [DB2_RECOVERY]
[TRACE] 2019-11-15 11:58:06,521 http-nio-8080-exec-2 org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - {} - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [54404535_1040_4a80ec20-bd06-4411-a6d0-9dc4f8412d41_19280504]
```

And then the update executes

```
[DEBUG] 2019-11-15 11:58:35,449 http-nio-8080-exec-2 org.hibernate.SQL - {} - update reconciliation_recovery_detail_test set reconciliation_id=? where recovery_date=? and recovery_type=? and reference_document_number=?
[TRACE] 2019-11-15 11:58:35,449 http-nio-8080-exec-2 org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - {} - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [152812]
[TRACE] 2019-11-15 11:58:35,449 http-nio-8080-exec-2 org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - {} - binding parameter [2] as [DATE] - [2019-11-10]
[TRACE] 2019-11-15 11:58:35,449 http-nio-8080-exec-2 org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - {} - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [DB2_RECOVERY]
[TRACE] 2019-11-15 11:58:35,449 http-nio-8080-exec-2 org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - {} - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [54404535_1040_4a80ec20-bd06-4411-a6d0-9dc4f8412d41_19280504]
```

I am saving the parent as - `entityManager.persist(reconciliationModel)`

I followed lot of articles on rightfully setting up the Bi directional OneToMany entity relationships and implemented accordingly. But there is a disconnect in my understanding, any help/pointers to resolve this issue would be really helpful.

Comment: There is 29 seconds between the insert and the update. I have a hard time believing that hibernate just updates for no good reason 29 seconds after the insert. The problem is probably your code.

Comment: Yeah that's because there are 6000 child items I am trying to save in this particular request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52313118/hibernate-5-java-bidirectional-onetomany-field-is-null-but-table-contains-data/52322624#52322624